# How to display second modal ViewController in UINavigationController programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6, uinavigationcontroller

In one of my `UINavigationController` views user can press "add" button to select photo from the album using `UIImagePickerController`. When user will select desired photo I want to move him to `AddPhotoViewController` view where he can add title and description than he can press "save" button to save data, dismiss `AddPhotoViewController` view and return to last `UINavigationController` view. So far I can only push `AddPhotoViewController` view and I can't do this as modal view. That is how I am doing that:

```
    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
      AddPhotoViewController *apvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addPhoto"];
      apvc.info = info;
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:apvc animated:YES];
      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   }
```

The code above works fine, but I want to add AddPhotoViewController as modal view . I wanted to use `presentModalViewController:animated:`, but it is depreciated in iOS 6.0. Than I tried:

```
   [self presentViewController:apvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

instead of:

```
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:apvc animated:YES];
```

but I am getting this error:

```
   Warning: Attempt to present <AddPhotoViewController: 0x1e183fc0> on <UINavigationController: 0x1d594a70> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Is it any way I could add a modal view on top of `UINavigationController` view after I dismiss my `UIImagePickerController` view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the navigation you are after thanks to the magic of the unwind segue...

In you first viewController,  implement an unwind segue

```
- (IBAction)unwindSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue
{
    NSLog (@"unwound");
       //you can extract data from your "addPhoto" viewController here
       //via segue.sourceViewController
}
```

Be sure to declare it in your header file.

In your "addPhoto" viewController, add a dismiss button of some kind, and CTRL-drag to the "exit" symbol at the foot of the controller. The unwind segue should be selectable.

To get to `addPhoto`, you can present it modally - but ask imagePickerController to do the presenting:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIViewController* addPhotoController = 
                [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addPhoto"];

    addPhotoController.infoDict = info; //passing the image data to addPhoto

    [picker presentViewController:addPhotoController 
                         animated:YES 
                       completion:nil];
}
```

So you do get two layers of presenting, but in each case it is the previous controller that does the presenting. DON"T dismiss the imagePickerController. When the unwind segue is executed, it will take care of the dismissing for you.

Answer (score 2):

First close the current modal controller before presenting the other controller. i.e

```
    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
          AddPhotoViewController *apvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addPhoto"];
          apvc.info = info;
          [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

          [self presentViewController:apvc animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
```

Comment: If I close my current modal view controller first than I will have parentview (UINavigationController in this case) visible for a second before new modal view will be shown. What I am looking for is to squeze new modal view between current modal view and parent view so if I close current modal view user will see new modal view instead of parent view. Do you think it is possible? Using indexes or something?

Comment: as far as I know without closing the current modal context, its not possible to open new modal context. I'm not sure what's your requirement is for opening again another modal with selected image, I would suggest you to go with pushing AddPhotoViewController into navController, once the operations are done with AddPhotoViewController, pop back to your parent view.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a segue? Setup your segue in story board and when returning from imagepickercontroller, just fire off the seque from code.

You can reference seque's http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html

Comment: The problem is if I will dismiss my UIImagePickerController first and than fire a segue - my UINavigationController will be visible (I know it is only one second or so, but it is still visible). I want user to see AddPhotoControllerView straight after he will pick a photo. So as I understand AddPhotoViewController view has to be added before UIImagePickerController view will be dismissed.

Comment: Have you tried not animating the pushing of the view controller without any animation?

Comment: Yes I tried that, even without animation you can still see UINavigationController view for like one second before new modal view is loaded. I found hacky solution which I posted above. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @nkongara's answer, but a little more robust by using the completion block to avoid any weird race conditions. Also, the code is a little more future-proof/bulletproof by calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion` on `[picker presentingViewController]` instead of assuming that `self` is always the presenting view controller.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    AddPhotoViewController *apvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addPhoto"];
    apvc.info = info;
    [[picker presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self presentViewController:apvc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not what I am looking for. I have explained above what I need.

Comment: I see... I'm not sure how standard what you're trying to do is in iOS and I can't think of an easy way to do it that doesn't feel hacky. Instead, what about this?  Present a UINavigationController with an instance of UIImagePickerController initialized as the rootViewController. Then, after the image is selected in the UIImagePickerController, you could push the AddPhotoViewController onto the presented UINavigationController. When the photo has successfully been added, you can dismiss the presented UINavigationController.  That's not exactly what you asked, but possibly more standard...

Answer (score 0):

As other people mentioned here it is not possible to add second modal view between current modal view and parent view. I solved my problem but it is more a hack than real solution. In case if someone want to do something similar this is link to the explanation: http://xissburg.com/presenting-multiple-modal-view-controllers-at-once/